# HERE Geocoder API: authentication problem

Tags: api, authentication, geolocation, here-api

I'm trying to reach the HERE Geocoder API. However, I receive

```
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
```

for all my requests, no matter the endpoint. The docs are not clear on whether dashes in the API key should be replaced with %2D so I've tried it both ways. I've tried it from browser and from a Node.js app. I'm trying to use the free tier of the HERE platform so I haven't added any payment infos yet. The site says "You are currently limited to 1000 location services requests a day."

I've tried the following calls (copied from various examples):

- [https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?apiKey={my](https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?apiKey=%7Bmy) API key}&in=countryCode%3ALTU&query=kreves%20pr.%2067
- [https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs?apiKey={my](https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs?apiKey=%7Bmy) API key}&indelim=%7C&outdelim=%7C&action=run&outcols=displayLatitude,displayLongitude,locationLabel,  houseNumber,street,district,city,postalCode,county,state,country&outputcombined=false

with

```
0001|Invalidenstraße 116 10115 Berlin|DEU
0002|Am Kronberger Hang 8 65824 Schwalbach|DEU
0003|425 W Randolph St Chicago IL 60606|USA
0004|One Main Street Cambridge MA 02142|USA
0005|200 S Mathilda Ave Sunnyvale CA 94086|USA
```

Even
[https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/autosuggest?at=40.74917,-73.98529&q=chrysler&apiKey={my](https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/autosuggest?at=40.74917,-73.98529&q=chrysler&apiKey=%7Bmy) API key}
gives me a

```
{
  status:503
  message:A critical upstream system connection problem.
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API key should not be edited by any means and should be used as it is.

It seems you already have an HERE self serve account with Limited Plan on HERE platform then you should be using the latest upgraded HERE API's instead of the legacy API's.

The API key generated on HERE Platform can not be used for legacy services, although  there are exceptions like : inherited customers.

I recommend to use the [HERE Geocoding & Search API v7](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/index.html), AKA GS7 service for autocomplete and places search endpoints.

Example request for Autocomplete endpoint using GS7: https://autocomplete.search.hereapi.com/v1/autocomplete?q=kreves&in=countryCode:LTU&apiKey=Your_API_KEY

Example request for Autosuggest endpoint using GS7:
https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=40.74917,-73.98529&q=chrysler&apiKey=Your_API_KEY

Please note, the HERE Batch Geocoder API is still not available for self serve customers.

Comment: I only wish the documentation were clear on all this.